# Загрузка пользователем фотографии в imageview

Tags: java, android, изображения, imageview, android-imageview

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог сам загружать фотографии в imageView из галереи?

Comment: откуда пользователь их загружать хочет?

Comment: С телефона, из своей галереи

Comment: Тогда вам на самом деле надо 2 вопроса: 1. Как загрузить изображение в ImageView из галереи. 2. Как сделать выбор изображения из галереи.   Задайте их отдельно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно системное активити галереи, сделать это можно так:

```
/**
 * Method for call native activity for pick images
 */
private void callPickedImageActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    // Show only images, no videos or anything else
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

В onActivityResult вам нужно получить результат, так:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE_REQUEST_CODE:
            extractPickedImages(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Method for extract result  picked images
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param resultCode
 * @param data
 */
private void extractPickedImages(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String realPath;

    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            imagesPathList = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (data.getData() != null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                    realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, data.getData());

                    // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
                else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                    realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, data.getData());

                    // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
                else
                    realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());


                Log.e(TAG, "imageEncoded:" + realPath);

            } else {
                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                        ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, uri);

                            // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
                        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, uri);

                            // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
                        else
                            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, uri);

                        Log.e(TAG, "imageEncoded:" + realPath);

                        imagesPathList.add(realPath);
                    }
                    Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

**RealPathUtil.java**

```
public class RealPathUtil {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri){
        String filePath = "";
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        // Split at colon, use second chat_view_item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        String result = null;

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                context,
                contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        if(cursor != null){
            int column_index =
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri){
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index
                = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Ну а установить в ImageView, можно так:

```
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```